# Erro PHP após consulta na tabela "Call to undefined function mysql_error()"

Tags: php

Tenho uma *query* de consulta de dados feitas em `PHP` versão **PHP Version 5.2.4**

Onde 1 à cada N consultas retorna o erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que seja uma exception pontual, mas deve haver alguma maneira de tratar isso.

A linha de código do qual o erro menciona logo após a *query* de consulta:

```
  $result_conhec = mssql_query($sql_conhec) or die ("E R R O R SQL_OCORR ". mssql_error());
```

Comment: Não parece que mssql_error () seja uma função válida em php. Você poderia tentar usar mssql_get_last_message http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mssql-get-last-message.php

Comment: mssql ou mysql? Reveja o título.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, PHP 5.2.4 é bem antigo, realmente seria melhor atualizar isto, baixar uma versão mais nova do Xampp ou Wamp.

Segundo, seu título fala `mysql_error` mas no seu código esta `mssql_error`, logo são funções diferentes, na verdade **`mssql_error`** não existe.

Se quer conectar com mySql então use `mysqli` ou `PDO` com [`PDO_MYSQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Se deseja se conectar com SqlServer, então use:

- [funções `sqlsrv`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php)
- [funções `odbc`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php)
- [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (com [`PDO_SQLSRV`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) ou [`PDO_ODBC`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php))

---

Com funções **`sqlsrv_`**

```
<?php
$serverName = 'serverName\nomeDaInstancia';

// SE não definir UID e PWD no $connectionInfoa conexão irá usar a autenticação do Windows.
$connectionInfo = array(
   'UID' => 'usuario',
   'PWD' => 'senha',
   'Database' => 'nomedobanco'
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ? OR bar = ?';
$params = array(1, 'texto');

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

---

Com funções **`obdc_`**:

```
$driver = 'tipo do driver do servidor cliente';
$server = 'servidor';
$database = 'banco';
$user = 'usuario';
$password = 'senha';

$Conn = odbc_connect("Driver=$driver;Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password) or die("E R R O R CONEXAO " . odbc_errormsg() );

$result = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 1 OR bar = 'texto'") or die("E R R O R SQL_OCORR " . odbc_errormsg($conn) );

while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
    for ($i=1;$i <= odbc_num_fields($result); $i++) {
        echo "Resultado: " . odbc_result($result, $i);
    }
}

odbc_close($);
```

---

Com **PDO** (`PDO_ODBC`):

```
$driver = 'tipo do driver do servidor cliente';
$server = 'servidor';
$database = 'banco';
$user = 'usuario';
$password = 'senha';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$driver;SERVERNAME=$server;DATABASE=$database",
          $user, $password);  
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}
```

Com **PDO** (`PDO_SQLSRV`):

Se for usar isto em um **hospedagem/servidor Windows** será necessário instalar [*SQLSRV 3.0*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx). Se precisa de suporte para PHP5.2 ou compilado no VC6, use este driver [*SQLSRV 2.0*](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV20.EXE).

```
$server = 'servidor';
$database = 'banco';
$user = 'usuario';
$password = 'senha';

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $user, $password);  
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}
```

---

Note que o valor da variável `$driver` em alguns dos exemplos vai depender de qual driver você tem instalado no teu servidor/hospedagem e no seu computador local (em ambos podem ser drivers diferentes), exemplos de drivers:

```
$driver = 'FreeTDS'; //Este é usado em algumas hospedagens Linux e Unix (como Mac OSX)
$driver = '{SQL Server}';
$driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}'; //versão 10
$driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'; //versão 11
$driver = '{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}'; //ODBC
```

Note que também existe um driver odbc para Linux: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28160